# Search and Replace with JQuery, php or other on full website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var tel1 = "<p>";
    var tel2 = "<h1>";
    var tel3 = "<h2>";
    var tel4 = "<h3>";

    if(tel4.html = "855-322-8671"){
        tel4.html ="<a href=\"tel:855-322-8671\">1-855-Factor-1</a>";
    }
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to do a search and replace through the whole site for these numbers and convert it into a `<a>` so you can call the number.  Any ideas with JQuery, or php?

Comment: you should use `==` in your `if` statement instead of `=`

Comment: please explain further.. i believe i may have a solution.... Is ur site on ur local computer? are these no.s same on all pages? if they change, how and when and where? etc

Comment: Not very clear what the usecase is, But do this on backend with php. simply insert anchor tags instead of creating `p & h` tags

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to extract the value from all the `<p>, <h1>, <h2>` and `<h3>` elements then your code should look like this. I am using the `<h3>` as an example.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      var tel4 = $("h3"); 
})
```

Here we are using jQuery to target all the `<h3>` elements and store the reference to those `<h3>` elements in the variable `var tel4`. It is a good practice to name such variables with a `$` before the name, like so `$tel4`.

We can then use the jQuery `.each()` function to loop over all the `<h3>` elements that were stored in our `tel4` variable and see if any of them contain the number `855-322-8671`.

```
$.each(tel4, function() {

    var number = "855-322-8671";
    var replacement = "1-855-Factor-1"
    if ($(this).is(':contains("' + number + '")')) {
        $(this).html(function() {
            return $(this).html().replace(number, replacement);
        })
    }
})
```

The above code will search every `<h3>` that contains the `number` and replace that number with our `replacement`.

Hope this helps!